# How can create Wakelock enter an Activity to HomeScreen

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I am a newbie in Android.
I wanna create a programing related to Wakelock.
When wakelock is acquired(it's as same as Alarm), an popup Activity is created and it enters HomeScreen directly.
How can I do it?

Comment: This is a too broad question with no indication of your efforts applied to solve your problem. Search for tutorials and examples, do some work and then ask if you encounter a specific problem

Answer (score 0):

**In manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

If your app includes a broadcast receiver that uses a service to do some work, you can manage your wake lock through a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, as described in Using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. This is the preferred approach. If your app doesn't follow that pattern, here is how you set a wake lock directly:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

**Using WakefulBroadcastReceiver**

***In manifest:***

```
<receiver android:name=".MyWakefulReceiver"></receiver>
```

The following code starts MyIntentService with the method startWakefulService()

```
public class MyWakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while the service is
            // launching. This is the Intent to deliver to the service.
            Intent service = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
            startWakefulService(context, service);
        }
    }
```

**Referance :**

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html